# Swift 4 Get multiples places from Google Places API

Tags: swift, api, google-places, gmsmapview, gmsplace

I have trouble with fetching multiples places from Google Places API. The problem is... if i fetch only one pin type like **Bar**s, its ok, no problem. But if i trying to get **Restaurants, Bars, Casino**... multiples types, it gives my only first place, in our case Restaurants.

I tried make same request with **Postman** with link below... but for example

- restaurants 1030 lines of JSON
- political 83 lines
- trying to get restaurants + political = 965 lines of JSON.

I use this code to get places i want:

```
func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, types:[String], completion: @escaping PlacesCompletion) -> Void {

    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(50000)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true&key=\(googleApiKey)"
    let typesString = types.count > 0 ? types.joined(separator: "|") : "food"
    urlString += "&types=\(typesString)"
    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) ?? urlString

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { completion([]); return }

    if let task = placesTask, task.taskIdentifier > 0 && task.state == .running {
        task.cancel()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    placesTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        if data != nil{
            for el in data!{
                //print(el)
            }
        }
        var placesArray: [PlaceContent] = []
        defer {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                completion(placesArray)
            }
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do{
            let decode = try JSONDecoder().decode(GooglePlacesAnswer.self, from: data)
            placesArray = (decode.results?.map{ $0.toPlaceContent() }) ?? []
        } catch let value{
            print(value.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    placesTask?.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get places for multiple types as stated in official documentation. You have to make multiple requests and combine the results.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

> type — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type.
>   Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all
>   types following the first entry are ignored). See the [list of
>   supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

Comment: Will be correct fetch all institutions and filter them after or make few requests to fetch all types i need?

Comment: Make a few requests to fetch all types you need